# Apache Tomcat WebApp freezes

Tags: java, apache, web-applications, tomcat, servlets

I've built a web app using java servlets and jsp pages and have run and tested it on my local machine and everything works fine, it gathers the results (given something to search for) and then displays them to the user.

I was recently asked to put my java program onto a server, running Apache tomcat 7.0.25. Now whenever I go to the page and try and run a search it lags out and never returns the response page even though all the back end process have completed properly and no errors have been thrown.

Unfortunately I can really display much of my code or the url for the program.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: how long does your search operation take? what does browser tell you?

Comment: do you have logging to confirm the processing completed? can you add more logging? Was a thread dump taken to check for stuck threads?

Comment: For some reason it all of a sudden began to work... i'm really confused, but it seems hard coding the paths works

Answer (score 0):

Increase the memory footprint by setting the CATALINA_OPTS or the JAVA_OPTS system variables, as described here:

http://vegdave.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/configure-heap-size-for-tomcat-6x/

Also, verify that everything between boxes is truly identical. Ensure your Tomcat and Java versions are identical between boxes ('java -version' and exec version.sh in the TOMCAT_HOME/bin directories). Another point to verify is whether one is 32-bit versus 64-bit as there may be different behaviors. Remember also that Tomcat needs to have write access to its own TOMCAT_HOME/logs directory to write to the catalina.out file -- the disk cannot be full and perms have to be adequate. Finally, check the system logs if all else fails as that is likely to provide a clue as to why something isn't working.

One last point of contention -- Is there anything running on your local system, perhaps even a different firewall setup, that might interfere with the application operation if it's different on the server. Boxes in public DCs are often configured with security in mind, so that's something to look into.

Comment: I have all my scripts and java code inside the webapp directory... would that have any effect on the outcome?

Comment: It may not be the best practice, but it should not. The assumption here is that you are building the app correctly because it ran locally (War deployment?).

Comment: Yes, I managed to move it out of the webapps directory and into another, which followed best practices. It seems the problem was the way I had hard-coded the directories to be followed